# weechat fresh installation OR reset all settings to default

Tags: irc

Being new to Ubuntu/Linux I've tried to quickly setup the newly installed `weechat` using [this proposed configuration](http://pascalpoitras.com/my-weechat-configuration/). Now, since it is hard to learn to use it, respectively get easy help AND `weechat` doesn't connect anymore, I want to totally **reset everything**.

I tried to un-/reinstall, but it keeps all settings. Also couldn't find any clue on-line.

Comment: Where did you save the file described in the tutorial?  Have you tried deleting said file?

Comment: Didn't make anything elese then copy paste the whole text (know it was naive) to the command line of `weechat`. Got a request it if I really want to paste them - over. However I've done (at least tried) some settings from this [introduction](http://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_quickstart.en.html) before. I really want to wipe out everything. Is this possible? Thank you :)

Comment: Run this command, and it will find any weechat directories in your user's home directory: `find /home/$USER -name '*weechat*' -type d`.  In theory, removing the paths it states (which are folders) will remove the weechat configuration settings.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank you! The command didn't work (I've put instead of `$USER` my user). However, I deleted the `.weechat` directory inside the `/home` directory. And it worked: after restarting it seems to be like new again :)

Comment: @alex Glad to hear it!  i've added that as an answer so you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to delete the weechat directories in your Home directory.

There may be a `.weechat` directory in your home directory.  If not, feel free to search for it with the command `find ~ -name '*weechat'* -type d` and delete any directories it returns.

Comment: I found a `~/.local/share/weechat/`  and `~/.config/weechat/`(Ubuntu 20.04).